# Python/Flask best practice for service layer

Tags: python, flask

I'm a little new to Python ( I come from a Java/C++ background ). I've been playing around with Flask for web development. My question relates somewhat to dependecy injection and thread safety. In the Java/Spring word you would have a Controller that has a Service say UserService injected into it. And when you have say a addUser endpoint it would call the userService.addUser(someData).

If I want to do the same in Python/Flask is it best practice to just have a file called UserService with functions like addUser(), deleteUser() etc and just straight call them with UserService.addUser(), UserService.deleteUser() and is this thread safe? Or should I have a new instance of User service in each endpoint?

Comment: No, following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it should be called `user_service` and the functions should be `add_user` and `delete_user`. Python has its own conventions for writing code, don't use Java-style names etc.

Comment: ok thanks, and is this style of just calling the function directly ex. user_servier.add_user( ) safe in a controller method.

Answer (score 30):

As with all things thread-related, the question is "did you make it thread-safe"?

If your user service looks like this:

```
# user_service.py
from some.package import database

def add_user(user_information=None):
    db = database.connect()
    db.insert(user_information)

def update_user(user_information=None):
    db = database.connect()
    db.update(user_information["user_id"], user_information)

def delete_user(user_id=None):
    db = database.connect()
    db.delete(user_id)
```

Then, assuming an even remotely sane implementation of `some.package.database` it will be thread safe.  If, on the other hand, you do something like this:

```
# bad_user_service.py
from some.package import database

# Shared single connection
# Probably *not* thread safe
db = database.connect()

def add_user(user_information=None):
    db.insert(user_information)

# ... etc. ...
```

Now, including `db = database.connect()` at the top of each of your service methods is very un-DRY.  You can avoid that issue by wrapping up your connection-specific work in a decorator (for example):

```
def provide_db(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        db = database.connect()
        return func(db, *args, **kwargs)

    return new_function
```

Then you could do this:

```
# user_service.py
from your.data.layer import provide_db

@provide_db
def add_user(db, user_information=None):
    db.insert(user_information)

# ... etc. ...
```

Comment: Should we connect to database each time? Isn't possible to use the same session? E.g. multiple calls to update_user().

Comment: It depends on what the warning label on `db.connect` says.  If it says "Must not be used across threads" then you probably want to re-connect every time (your library will tell you how to optimize for connection latency).  If it says "thread-safe" then you can do something much more module-level-like.

Comment: Looks like we could create a singleton for the database connection. If the library does not support that, a critical section could be created in the singleton to serialize the access for the method calls., but if the library indicates to create a new instance, that would be the best way to go.